Saving user in foreign key model field produces unknown column in field list error
Creating ability on a web page for a user to upload a note against a watchlist item, see code below. Error - (1054, "Unknown column 'created_by_id' in 'field list'").
I am using ModelForms, all my models are managed=False which is why I am specifying the PK fields in the models. I have run migrations multiple times and it doesnt detect any changes.
Any help to understand why I am getting this error would be very appreciated.
models.py - related portion
class UserNotes(models.Model):
    note_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    watchlist = models.ForeignKey('Watchlist', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_uploads'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Note title: {self.title}"

views.py - related portion
        if request.method == "POST":
            add_note_form = UserNote(request.POST)
            if add_note_form.is_valid():
                add_note = add_note_form.save(commit=False)
                print(f"add_note: {add_note}")
                add_note.created_by = request.user
                add_note.save()
                print(f"note saved: {add_note_form}")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

forms.py - related portion
class UserNote(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserNotes
        fields = ['title', 'note']
        widgets = {
            "note": forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'user_note'})
        }

        labels = {
            'title': 'Title',
            'note': 'Note'
        }

I thought the form only needed to have fields that were to be presented to the html template included in the Meta? Im trying to add the user after .save(commit=False) so that it is added to the other form fields that are being saved through the model.

For anyone looking at this I believe the error is that one one of the FK (watchlist) in the model was marked as not null in the db schema but not in the model, testing to confirm this will resolve.
